# Translating "jmd. anführen"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english, french

> Er aber fuhr mich an, auch er und alle dächten an uns.

I see two possibilities:

- But he raised, that also him and all were thinking about us
- But he tried to fool me saying that also him and all were thinking about us

The second version has a nuance of deception corresponding to an informal acception of "anführen". It could be rephrased as

- But he fibbed saying that …
- But he purported that …

Do you feel this second nuance when reading the german sentence? How would you propose to translate?

Regards

Comment: I think you are talking about "[jmd. anfahren (7)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anfahren)"

Comment: @amadeusamadeus, ich habe Ihren Editierversuch, *anführen* in *anfahren* zu ändern abgelehnt. Die Verwechselung der Verben hat ja offenbar erst dazu geführt, dass diese Frage überhaupt gestellt wurde. SIe ist folglich auch der Kern meiner Antwort. Ihre Änderung würde Frage und Antwort obsolet machen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Er aber *fuhr mich an*, auch er und alle dächten an uns.

I think, the confusion lies in the meaning of *fuhr jemand an*. This is the preterite tense of *jemand anf**a**hren* (see [meaning [6]](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anfahren)), which translates to *snapping or snarling at somebody*.

The verb form that you erroneously thought of is *jemand anf**ü**hren* (see [meanings [1] and [4]](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anf%C3%BChren)), which translates to *leading somebody* or *fooling somebody*, respectively. In preterite tense this is *führte jemand an*.